# How do I use this state machine with my movement code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, state-machine

I finished watching a couple tutorials on state machines in unity and I'm now trying to figure out how I can actually use one with my player movement code, but I'm a bit stuck. The tutorial I followed had shown to do a StateManager script like this

```
public class PlayerStateManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerBaseState currentState; 
    public PlayerJumpState jumpState = new PlayerJumpState();
    public PlayerIdleState idleState = new PlayerIdleState();
    public PlayerRunState runState = new PlayerRunState();

    void Start()
    {
        currentState = idleState;

        currentState.EnterState(this);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        currentState.UpdateState(this);
    }

    public void SwitchState(PlayerBaseState state)
    {
        currentState = state;
        state.EnterState(this);
    }
}
```

And now I assumed all I would need to do to use this was this

```
public class TestMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerStateManager playerState;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            playerState.SwitchState(playerState.jumpState);
        }
    }
}
```

But this clearly isn't correct since I keep getting an error saying "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the line with SwitchState.

Comment: Check if you have any object associated too your playerState variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `TestMovement`, do you have a `Start` or `Awake` method which assigns something to the `playerState` field? If not, that field is never assigned and is therefore always null.

Another thing you could do is make it `public PlayerStateManager playerState;` and assign something to it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

playerState is private by default so you have to make public or [SerializeField] and introduce it in the game engine